# Como formatar todos os elementos de um list em Python?

Tags: python, lista

Em php, quando eu quero gerar um `array` formatado, eu utilizo a função `array_map`.

Assim:

```
$numeros = range(1, 10);

array_map(function ($value) {
    return sprintf('%04', $value);
}, $numeros);
```

Retorna:

```
array('0001', '0002', '0003', '0004' ...);
```

Já em `python`, para essa `list` `range(1, 10)` como eu poderia fazer essa mesma operação?

Existe alguma maneira curta e simples de se fazer isso (igual ou melhor que no PHP)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim.

```
numeros = list(range(1, 10))
resultado = [str(x).zfill(4) for x in numeros]
```

Comment: O cara colocou um "Sim" só para não ficar apenas código. Gostei dessa função `zfill`. Bom saber que existe isso em `python`, sem precisar ficar criando

Comment: A solução está corretissima, mas o zfill raramente é usado. Em geral se usa o método `format` das strings, que tem toda uma mini-linguagem de formatação e pode fazer muito mais do que só preencher zeros. Com format, seria:
`resultado = ["{:04d}".format(x) for x in range(1,10)]

Comment: Alias - nesse caso não há necessidade nenhumissimanissima de se usar  `list(range(..))` - o comportamento do `for` é identico tanto para o range de Python 2 quanto para o range de Python 3

Comment: @jsbueno, nosso menino pythonico

Answer (score 3):

Apenas como complemento da resposta do [@CiganoMorrizonMender](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/95182/4995):

Essa operação, em `Python`, é chamada de [List Comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

Ele pode ser usado para construir as listas de uma forma muito simples.

Se o objetivo é somente criar a lista formatada, sem a necessidade de ter o valor não-formatado em uma variável, podemos simplesmente já fazer a seguinte declaração diretamente, sem criar uma variável antes.

```
senhores = ['Senhor %s' % (nome) for nome in ['wallace', 'cigano', 'bigown']]
```

Retorno é:

```
['Senhor wallace', 'Senhor cigano', 'Senhor bigwon']
```