# Diferença entre "list(range(1, 10))" e "range(1, 10)"?

Tags: python, lista

Fiz essa pergunta aqui [Como formatar todos os elementos de um list em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95177/como-formatar-todos-os-elementos-de-um-list-em-python).

Em uma das respostas, o @CiganoMorrisonMendez, colocou o seguinte trecho:

```
list(range(1, 10))
```

Porém, sempre que utilizei o `Python`, eu utilizei

```
range(1, 10)
```

Isso se trata de uma conversão para `list`? Mas o `range` já não retorna um `list`?

## Atualização

Fiz um teste na linha de comando e o resultado que foi retornado foi esse:

```
type(range(1, 10))
<type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não.

[`range` é uma classe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) que pode ser inicializada com três argumentos: início, fim e incremento. Portanto, não é igual uma lista.

Ela pode gerar uma lista se convertida para lista porque possui capacidade de ser iterada.

No Python 2, o comportamento era outro. `range` efetivamente gerava uma lista. No Python 3, o objeto se assemelha mais a uma gerador.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na atualização. O terminal está falando que ele é um list!

Comment: Está escrito que _range atualmente é um tipo de  sequência imutável_. Esse "atualmente" quer dizer "foi modificado em versões recentes"?

Comment: Sim, vou melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Só para completar - algumas ferramentas que atualizam o código para funcionar simultaneamente com Python 2 e Python 3 mudam as ocorrências de `range` em Python 2 para `list(range(...))` - de forma que o comportamento seja idêntico nas duas versões.